# What is the difference between object.method(a,b) and method(a,b) in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, arguments

I am very new to programming and am trying to learn Ruby. I can't quite get my head around methods at the moment. I uderstand that:

Methods allow me to execute a chunk of code without having to rewrite it, such a method looks like:

```
example_method
```

Arguments allow me to pass values into the code within the method that go in the place of the placeholders defined in the method. This way I can execute a set of code with different inputs. Methods with arguments look like:

```
example_method( x , y )
```

But I am confused about what an instantiation of a method on an object is actually doing. For example:

```
object.example_method( x, y )
```

What does this mean? Why is the method attached to an object with the period notation? Do we do this so we can reference **Instance** / **Class variables** of the object within our method? Is there any other reason to do this?

For the example if:

```
def example_method(x , y)
  x * y
end
```

Will `object.exaple_method(a , b)` be the same as `example_method(a , b)` ?

Thanks for any help, sorry if I am not being clear.

Comment: Remember to edit your post and format the code properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby is an [*Object Oriented*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) language. This means that objects not only have members (=state) but also methods (=behavior). When you are calling a method on an object (is which case the object is called the *caller*) the method that runs is the method which corresponds to **this object's type behavior**.

When you are calling a method with no caller, `self` is implicitly the caller. From irb, `self` is considered `main`, or global scope.

Example:

```
def my_method(a)
  "#{a} from main"
end

class A
  def my_method(a)
    "#{a} from A"
  end
end

class B
  def my_method(a)
    "#{a} from B"
  end
end

a = A.new
b = B.new

my_method(1)
# => "1 from main"
a.my_method(1)
# => "1 from A"
b.my_method(1)
# => "1 from B"
```

Comment: Thanks! This is starting to click now. If a caller has no Local Scope method would it then inherit the Global Scope method instead?

Comment: @Cu1ture Trying to call a method on an object which does not exist in the object's type will result in an `undefined method` error

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when calling a method with no Caller is the whole contents of the program being considered an object that the method is calling on then?

Comment: @Cu1ture - that depends on _where_ you are calling it from. If you are calling it from _within_ an object (inside one of its methods) - the object itself is considered the caller. If it is called on the global scope itself, then yes, the global scope is itself considered an object.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks Uri you really helped me sort that out in my head. Now to try and understand Class Methods :)

Comment: @Cu1ture - if it answered your question - accept it

Answer (score 0):

If I assume correctly what you're asking it's a class method vs an instance method

```
def Object
  def self.example_method(x, y)
    #this is a class method
    x * y
  end

  def example_method(x,y)
    #this is an instance method
    x * y
  end
end
```

So now we've defined them here's how we call them

```
#This called the class method
Object.example_method(3,3) => 9

#To call the instance method we have to have an instance
object = Object.new
object.example_method(3,3) => 9
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, its more that I dont understand the difference between a method that is called on an object and a method that is not called on an object.

Comment: @Cu1ture: methods are always called on an object. If you don't explicitly specify a receiver, then the receiver is implicitly `self`.