# How can I differentiate between methods called on the implicit receiver and variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, self

I'm learning Ruby and have just encountered implicit receivers for methods e.g. when I call the method `normalize` without specifying a receiver it is interpreted with an implicit receiver as `self.normalize`.

My question is when someone is reading my code how can they easily tell that `normalize` is a method called on the implicit receiver and not a variable such as `normalize = "normalize"`?

It seems to me that both when it is a method call `normalize` and when it is a variable `normalize` they appear identical in the code.

Comment: If it is not obvious immediately or after scanning previous 5 lines, you likely have some bigger problems with your code.

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24915354/what-is-the-difference-between-object-methoda-b-and-methoda-b-in-ruby?rq=1

Comment: It just seemed a bit suprising given that nealy everything in ruby has a naming convention to make it obviouse what it is that the two look identical. But I am assuming your answer is saying there is no self contained way of differentiating them without checking the rest of the code.

Comment: Yep, there is a naming convention here too. Why would you call a variable like a method? Use verbs for methods (`normalize`) and nouns for variables (`normalized_value`)

Comment: I see, but there is no hard wired naming convention such as when you define an instance variable it is preceded by @. This is just something I should just be aware of when naming my methods / variables?

Comment: The `@` in instance variable names is not a naming convention. It's a syntax requirement.

Comment: You know the famous saying? "There are only two hard things in programming: cache invalidation and naming things". Without naming things properly, you'll be able to produce unreadable code in any language, no matter how syntactically strict.

Comment: Haha very good, I will keep that in mind!

Comment: I just worked on an app where everything was `a1`, `a2`, `b1`, etc - it was terrible. I think the worst part was that I never figured out what determined whether the letter or number should be incremented...

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: "There are only two hard things in programming: cache invalidation, naming things and off-by-one errors."

Comment: @JörgWMittag: yeah, that is a follow-up on the original joke, IIRC :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Interesting: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/19836/261 I always blindly assumed the quote was by Phil Karlton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ever you use `=`, as in your example of `normalize = "normalize"`, it will set a variable local to the block - you would need to explicitly add the `self.` to assign an attribute. The explicit receiver of self only comes into play when you are not assigning via `=`.

Also, to summarize what is in the comments:

There is a naming convention here too. Use verbs for methods (normalize) and nouns for variables (normalized_value).

A good IDE, like RubyMine, (and even many plain editors) will use syntax highlighting to make a visual distinction, but if it is not obvious immediately or after scanning previous 5 lines, you likely have some bigger problems with your code.

Comment: Also, @RAJ is right, there is some good relevant info in the answers to your other question.